# If field1 is equal to field2 and field3 is equal to "Sim" then copy field3&4 to field5

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, ms-office

can someone help with this formula in excell 2013?

this is what i need:

if this is true

```
=if(Tabela2[@[Nº Clínico]]='Fichas Clinicas'!D5;"True";"False")
```

then

if this is true

```
=if('Fichas Clinicas'!D158="Sim";"True";"False")
```

then

```
=T("SIM: "&'Fichas Clinicas'!D167)
```

else

do nothing

thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to say field2 is a Row where the value from field1(column) must be compare with all from that row.

Comment: Would you mind adding some example data and perhaps the desired output in your question. I think it might help clear up what you mean by "field2 is a row where the value from field1(column) must be compared.."

Comment: any better?   if cell1.sheet1 is equal to row2.sheet2 and cell3.sheet2 where cell1.sheet1 matches row2.sheet2 is equal to "sim" then write in cell4.sheet1 the values from cell3.sheet2 and cell4.sheet2

Answer (score 0):

Going off of this comment: "There are many field so i put then vertically instead of horizontal. this is way confusing... if cell1.sheet1 is equal to row2.sheet2 and cell3.sheet2 where cell1.sheet1 matches row2.sheet2 is equal to "sim" then write in cell4.sheet1 the values from cell3.sheet2 and cell4.sheet2"

For the sake of clarity:

```
cell1.Sheet1 = Sheet1!A1
row2.sheet2 = Sheet2!2:2
cell3.sheet2 (this is actually an entire row I believe) = Sheet2!3:3
cell4.sheet1 = Sheet1!A2
cell4.sheet2 (this is actually an entire row also) = Sheet2!4:4
```

Then in Sheet2!A4 put the formula:

```
=offset(Sheet2!A3, 0, SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$1=Sheet2!A2:IV2)*(Sheet2!A3:IV3="sim")*column())) & offset(Sheet2!A4, 0, SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$1=Sheet2!A2:IV2)*(Sheet2!A3:IV3="sim")*column()))
```

This is as complicated of an answer as the question itself. Give me a few minutes and I'll explain it in an edit

Explanation: The bit before the `&`: The sumproduct here will return the column number where your cell1's value is in Row 2 of your Sheet2 AND the value "sim" is in row 4 of your Sheet2. The `offset` formula will start cellA3 of Sheet2 (This is the 3rd row of the sheet) and it will grab the value from the column where the SumProduct found "sim" and cell1's value. The bit after the '&' is doing the same thing, but it's grabbing the value from Row 4 of Sheet2 (cell4.sheet2).

You'll probably need to massage this a bit to make it work, but the big takeaway here is that you need to search two rows for two seperate conditions and get the column where both conditions are true. This is what that SumProduct will do. You then need to concatenate the values of two cells in that same column, this is what the the two offsets are doing for you. Granted, it's ugly, but with a bit of massaging, it should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks ill try but i Forgot to say field2 is a Row where the value from field1(column) must be compare with all from that row.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on this. Perhaps instead of using "Field" to explain things, use proper excel terms like "Column" "Row" "Cells", etc.  I'm getting a bit hung up on the "Field2 is a row"... that is very confusing.

Comment: There are many field so i put then vertically instead of horizontal.                                                        this is way confusing...      if cell1.sheet1 is equal to row2.sheet2 and cell3.sheet2 where cell1.sheet1 matches row2.sheet2 is equal to "sim" then write in cell4.sheet1 the values from cell3.sheet2 and cell4.sheet2

Comment: Try like this, maybe its easier:  Sheet1
cell1


sheet2
cellA(Row5)
cellB
cellC                                                                when adding id(number) to cell1 he will check if there is an equal id(number) in cellA 
if there is none do nothing 
else check if cellB in column where cellA match cell1 is equal to "Sim" 
if not do nothing 
else write the value from cellB and cellC

Comment: Thanks but i think i found an easier way, check my post and look at the loggic i think i only need to have 2 if statementes and a write one.

Comment: shouldnt this work?                                                                         =if(and(Tabela2[@[Nº Clínico]]='Fichas Clinicas'!D5, 'Fichas Clinicas'!D158="Sim"),T("SIM: "&'Fichas Clinicas'!D167),"NAO")

Comment: its working, just add ; instead of , between the two if statments

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(Tabela2[@[Nº Clínico]]='Fichas Clinicas'!D5; 'Fichas Clinicas'!D158="Sim");T("SIM: "&'Fichas Clinicas'!D167);"Nao")

Comment: but now when i drag in order to apply it to a column it changes the wrong values.

ex:

=SE(E(Tabela2[@[Nº Clínico]]='Fichas Clinicas'!B5; 'Fichas Clinicas'!B158="Sim");T("SIM: "&'Fichas Clinicas'!B167);"Nao")

when i drag it it change the numbers but i need it to change B to C, D, E etc...

is it possible or do i have to change them manually?